# Extent Report: Not able to see the screenshots on other machine

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, extent

I am able generate the extent reports with screenshots on my local machine.
But when i mail the reports to someone else, or open the html on a differant machine, the screenshots are not visible. It says that the path is invalid.

While attaching the screenshot, i am giving the path of my local machine. And it is searching the same path on other machine too.
I tried zipping the html and pics in one folder too.

Please help me how to attach the screenshots into html file without local machine dependency.

Comment: Hello @Nishant, did you find any solution for this. If yes please let me  know. i am also facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using base64 conversion of the obtained screenshots.
Use the following code in your framework and try it.

```
public static String addScreenshot() {
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) BasePage.driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String encodedBase64 = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = null;
    try {
        fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(scrFile);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)scrFile.length()];
        fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
        encodedBase64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "data:image/png;base64,"+encodedBase64;
}
```

Comment: This code is working okay but In extent report, when I click on the embedded image it's shows something like this. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16231354/41188053-0182fa8e-6b75-11e8-91ac-bcb488024706.jpg

Comment: Yes ,  Thumbnail  view is ok but when click on the screenshot image get distorted.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue.

Share the folder in which you are storing the screenshots with everyone  and return same path in below method.

```
public static String getScreenshot(WebDriver oDriver, String ScreenShotName) throws IOException
    {
        String dateName=new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDDHHMMSS").format(new Date());
        TakesScreenshot ts=(TakesScreenshot)oDriver;
        File source=ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String destination=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/FailedScreenshots/"+ScreenShotName+dateName+".png";
        File finalDestination=new File(destination);
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, finalDestination);

        String Imagepath="file://Machinename/FailedScreenshots/"+ScreenShotName+dateName+".png";
        return Imagepath;
    }
```

Hope this helps!