# Not able to view screenshot in Jenkins while it's visible in local machine

Tags: jenkins, extentreports

I am able to view my screenshot for failed test cases in a local machine, but not in Jenkins. I am using ExtentReports.

[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDNTJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you need help with something please provide screenshots, exceptions and your code otherwise no one can realldy help you.

Comment: I am getting image path after inspecting but not visible, it might be some security issue in jenkins:I<li><img class="r-img" onerror="this.style.display=&quot;none&quot;" data-featherlight="D:\Users\apoorv.r\workspace\MYWU1/Screenshots/Apply20190304124708.png" src="D:\Users\apoorv.r\workspace\MYWU1/Screenshots/Apply20190304124708.png" data-src="D:\Users\apoorv.r\workspace\MYWU1/Screenshots/Apply20190304124708.png" style="display: none;"></li>

Comment: By default, Extent Reports expects screenshots to be in the same folder as the report itself.  Are you specifying a different folder for the report file versus the screenshot files?  That can be done, but there's caveats to that.

Comment: But same is visible in local machine in report.

Comment: Tried but doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extent Report: Not able to see the screenshots on other machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062006/extent-report-not-able-to-see-the-screenshots-on-other-machine)

Comment: didn't help, jenkins is blocking image while loading. I think its some security issue. Still unresolved.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, you have both backward and forward slashes. Configure correctly in all the places with "\" [Preferable way]